OPNsense NAT Reflection not working for Router but for the other LAN
I have the following setup:
              ISP
               |
               |
    Router 192.168.0.1
                |
              /   \
            /       \
          /           \
     webserver       other lan clients
     192.168.0.2    192.168.0.3-100 (from dhcp)

My Router is not able to connect to the webserver via it's public IP-address but the rest of the 192.168.0.0/24 net can.
I have set portforwards for the WAN interface on port 80 and 443 to my webserver and enabled "Reflection for port forwards" as well as "Automatic outbound NAT for Reflection" in the advanced settings for the firewall.
Anyone got an idea why my router is not able to connect to the webserver via it's external-IP.
